# Is sign convention necessary in the following equation?

Tags: optics, conventions, refraction, lenses

[image]

The above diagram is used to derive the following equation which is about the refraction due to the spherical surface.

$$\frac{n_2}{v} - \frac{n_1}{u} = \frac {n_2-n_1}{R}$$

The above equation is derived using all the sign conventions i.e. the object distance is taken negative when measured opposite to the direction of the incident ray and all such rules.

So, we used sign conventions while deriving the equation but when we use this equation while solving questions, then also we use sign conventions. It's not intuitive to me. Why do we use sign conventions 2 times? Wouldn't that cancel the effect of what we did while deriving?
For example: While deriving the above equation we took u = -u, i.e. object distance to be negative. Now when I am solving questions and object distance is given for instance 60cm, then I have to take u = -60. Why is that?

Comment: Actually no. Although it is derived from a special situation which call as sign convention, this formula is valid for all situations. Yes, it would cancel the effect, when we substitute the values, *but it would for all variables* so it wouldn't give us wrong results.

Comment: well you are correct, but I am come to know recently that it is good to follow sign conventions. It is true that the effect cancels out eventually as per my observation, but that is only true for convex lense. The effect doe not cancel out in case of concave lense. So if we need a general formula for lenses, we should follow sign conventions, otherwise the formula would be different for concave and convex